# Best practices of writing a good usage output for a program

Tags: python, console, usage-message

I've been looking online a lot for guidelines that explains how to write a good usage output of a program.

Lets say I have some little program written in Python:

```
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv < 5):
        print("Wrong usage")
    else:
        #Do something with the 4 parameters
        #First two looks like this: -s1 SOMETHING1
        #Second two looks like this: -s2 SOMETHING2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And lets say I'm calling this program like this:

`py someProgram.py -s1 SOMETHING1 -s2 SOMETHING2`

first 2 arguments are required, and the other 2 parameters aren't.

**What would be a good practice of a usage message ?**

I thought of something like this :

`Usage: py program.py -p1 param1 [-p2 param2]`

Is this right ? I feel like the `-p1 param1` part is wrong, it just doesn't look right.

**EDIT:**
Ok, I'm getting super lost at the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) documentation.
Can someone please provide a simple example of my need ? Is it possible to connect 2 parameters together ? lets say if I'm trying to access args.u it will give me the param1 value ?

Comment: Use `argparse` and you get a usage message for free

Comment: @DeepSpace This looks interesting, never knew this module existed, I will look into it.  But this is more of a general question of what are the guidelines of writing a usage message.  I tried reading this [guideline](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/general/usage.html) but it really isn't clear when I want 2 parameters to be in the same group, for example `-p1 param1`.

Comment: Notice that *most* programs today use a single hyphen for one-letter options, and two hypens for multi-letter options. Thus `-p1 param1` would be the single-letter option `-p` with argument `1`, followed by the non-option argument `param1`. This is confusing. If you intend `param1` to be a parameter to the option `-p1`,  then the syntax should probably be `--p1 param1` or `--p1=param1`. argparse will handle this. If you write Python, I *strongly* recommend that you use argparse. Also, check out the GNU Coding Standards. I do not completely agree with either, but they give some uniformity

Comment: @TurePålsson There's no standard for this or some conventions ? Also why the double "-" ? And I'm asking it not just for python language.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-p', type=str)
ap.add_argument('-q', type=int)
ap.add_argument('-x', action='store_true')
ap.add_argument('infile', type=str)
args = ap.parse_args()
```

and the user says

```
python3 your_program.py -p foo -q 17 -x hello.txt
```

then `args.p` will contain the string foo, `args.q` will contain the integer 17, `args.x` will be `True`, and `args.infile` will contain the string `hello.txt`.

Comment: How will it output the correct usage if I'm not providing any argument ? What will be the name of the variable after `-p` ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? As it happens, the argument to the -p option will be called P (i.e, the name converted to uppercase) but that can be changed using the metavar parameter, [as described in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar).